# Link Manager for Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I'm looking for is a program that draws dependency graphs for Excel spreadsheets where one spreadsheet depends on another if it links to it.

Ideally, I would also be able to right-click a spreadsheet in the file-explorer and "see" what other spreadsheets in the filesystem depend on this spreadsheet and which spreadsheets that this spreadsheet depends on.

I can think of lots of other features I would like (such as the ability to change and update links in batches, etc), but the two above would be the best.

Does anything like this exist?  If so, it would really improve the workflow at my office.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free [Workbooks Statistics Add-In](http://www.lyquidity.com/workbookstatistics/) to check all the dependencies originating from one workbook.

Comment: great link with helpful addins